# Android Studio's Find All not working per module

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea

Am I missing something, it looks like the Find all/Search all occurrence is not working with **module** as filter?

Filter via Project
[image]

Filter via module
[image]

Comment: Please try File | Invalidate Caches | Invalidate and Restart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a newer Android Studio release, search functionaliy was changed a little bit.

A very simple demo application has search `modules` like:

- demo
- demo.app
- demo.androidTest
- demo.main
- demo.unitTest

`demo.app` will search in non source code files under `app` directory like `.gitignore`, `build.gradle`, `proguard-rules.pro` ...

`demo.main` will search in `app/src/main`.

You may try searching `minSdk` in `demo.app` and probably you will find build.gradle file.

If you search `!!` in `demo.main`, you may get expected search results.